# How to access an element in the structure which not the first - Qsort

Tags: c

I am trying to sort the following structure. I am using the qsort to order the books according to date publish in order of the newest first. I completely don't understand why the pointer can't access the date-published element.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "problem5.h"

int int_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    //const int *ia = (const int *)a;
    //const int *ib = (const int *)b;
    //return *ia - *ib;
    return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}


int main()
{
  struct book* books = NULL;     // no books at all initially so we initialize to NULL
                                 // so we can simply use realloc
  int numberofbooks = 0;
  int programend = 0;

  while (programend == 0)
  {
    printf("1. Add Book\n");
    printf("2. View Books\n");
    printf("3. Quit\n");
    int command;
    int i, j;
    scanf("%d", &command);

    if (command == 1)
    {
      getchar();   // consume Enter key (due su scanf)

      // allocate memory for one more book
      books = realloc(books, sizeof(struct book) * (numberofbooks + 1));

      printf("Enter Name\n");
      gets(books[numberofbooks].name);

      printf("Enter Author\n");
      gets(books[numberofbooks].author);

      printf("Enter Year Published\n");
      scanf("%d", &books[numberofbooks].year_published);

      numberofbooks++;   // increment number of books
      printf(books.year_published);
    }
    else if (command == 2)
    {

      qsort(books->year_published, numberofbooks, sizeof(int), int_cmp);
      for (i = 0; i < numberofbooks; i++)
      {
        printf("%d - %s by %s\n", books[i].year_published, books[i].name, books[i].author);
      }
    }
    else if (command == 3)
    {
      programend = 1;
    }
    //else if and the else will prevent infinite loop when the user enters invalid choice in the beginning.
    else if (command != 1 || command != 2 || command != 3)
    {
      printf("Invalid choice!\n");
    }
    else {return 0;}
  }
  free(books);

  return 0;
}
```

I think the problem is the pointer in the qsort() but I don't know how to correct that. I tried using qsort(books, numberofbooks, sizeof(int), int_cmp); but the books weren't ordered as expected.

Comment: Tip: Learn about `switch` and how it can simplify your `command` branching.

Comment: Tip: Don't pre-declare things like `i`, put that in the context in which it's used, like `for (int i = 0; ...)`. This means the definitions are close at hand, there's no need to go hunting for them to verify they're correct, and no chance of them being used somewhere else.

Comment: Tip: If you have an `if` chain with conditions A, B and C, then the last condition will by definition be `!A && !B && !C`. There's no need to double-test. Just use an `else`.

Comment: You want to sort by the _entire_ list of records. Possibly with multiple keys. Let's assume it's by `year_published` (e.g). You want: `qsort(books,numberofbooks,sizeof(struct book),cmp_record);` and `int cmp_record(const void *a,const void *b) { const struct book *booka = a; const struct book *bookb = b; return booka->year_published - bookb->year_published; }`

Comment: *Never* use `gets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of a multikey sort:

```
int
cmp_multikey(const void *a,const void *b)
{
    const struct book *booka = a;
    const struct book *bookb = b;
    int cmp;

    do {
        // sort by year published
        cmp = booka->year_published - bookb->year_published;
        if (cmp)
            break;

        // sort by author
        cmp = strcmp(booka->author,bookb->author);
        if (cmp)
            break;

        // sort by title
        cmp = strcmp(booka->name,bookb->name);
        if (cmp)
            break;
    } while (0);

    return cmp;
}
```

---

Invoke with:

```
qsort(books,numberofbooks,sizeof(struct book),cmp_multikey);
```

---

Some other tips ...

[As others have mentioned] *Never* use `gets`. Use a `switch/case` instead of an `if/else` ladder.

Try to avoid intermixing `scanf` and `fgets`.

Personally, I prefer to [always] use `fgets`. Here is a [safe] replacement for `gets` and a replacment for `scanf("%d",&num);`:

```
int
getstr(const char *prompt,char *buf,int buflen)
{
    char *cp;

    printf("%s",prompt);
    fflush(stdout);

    cp = fgets(buf,buflen,stdin);
    if (cp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"unexpected EOF\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // find newline
    cp = strchr(buf,'\n');

    // ensure we had enough space
    if (cp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"response too large for buffer\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // strip newline
    *cp = 0;
}

int
getnum(const char *prompt)
{
    char buf[1000];
    int num;

    getstr(prompt,buf,sizeof(buf));

    num = atoi(buf);

    return num;
}
```

Comment: I used the qsort() code you wrote in your comment and it worked well for me.  Thanks for the fgets() and switch/case suggestions. They work better than my initial code. I also got the general understanding of sorting in C. Thanks.