# Program stopped midway and it is not terminating unless I press ctrl+c

Tags: c, set, adjacency-matrix

This is my code to find if a relation is equivalent by using adjacency matrix and compute the equivalence class

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int mat[10][10], setln, relln, n, i, j;
char set[10], rel[50];
int checkrel(char);
int reflexive();
int symmetric();
int transitive();
int display();
int adjacency();
void main()
{
    int check = 1, r, s, t;
    printf("Enter the no. of elements in the set: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    gets(set);
    printf("Enter the elements of the set: ");
    fgets(set, 10, stdin);
    setln = strlen(set);
    while (check == 1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the elements of relation in the manner '(a,b)(b,d)...':\n");
        fgets(rel, 50, stdin);
        relln = strlen(rel);
        if (relln < 5)
            continue;
        for (i = 0; i < relln - 5; i + 5)
        {

            if (rel[0] == '(' && (checkrel(rel[1])) && rel[2] == ',' && (checkrel(rel[3])) && rel[4] == ')')
                check = 0;
            else
            {
                printf("Enter a valid relation");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    adjacency();
    r = reflexive();
    s = symmetric();
    t = transitive();
    if (r == 1)
        printf("\nThe relation is reflexive");
    else
        printf("\nThe relation is not reflexive");
    if (s == 1)
        printf("\nThe relation is symmetric");
    else
        printf("\nThe relation is not symmetric");
    if (t == 1)
        printf("\nThe relation is transitive");
    else
        printf("\nThe relation is not transitive");
    if (r == 1 && s == 1 && t == 1)
        printf("\nTherefore the relation is equivalent");
    else
        printf("\nTherefore the relation is not equivalent");
    int display();
    getchar();
}
int checkrel(char a)
{
    int m;
    for (int i = 0; i < setln; i++)
    {
        if (a == set[i])
            m = 1;
    }
    if (m == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int adjacency()
{
    int a, b;
    for (i = 1, j = 3; i < relln - 3; i + 5, j + 5)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < setln; k++)
        {
            if (rel[i] == set[k])
                a = k;
        }
        for (int l = 0; l < setln; l++)
        {
            if (rel[j] == set[l])
                b = l;
        }
        mat[a][b] = 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (mat[i][j] != 1)
                mat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
int reflexive()
{
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (mat[i][i] != 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
int symmetric()
{
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (mat[i][j] != mat[j][i])
            {
                printf("\nThe relation is not equivalent as it is not symmetric");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
int transitive()
{
    int k;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (mat[i][j] == 1)
            {
                for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
                {
                    if (mat[j][k] == 1 && mat[i][k] != 1)
                    {
                        printf("\nThe relation is not equivalent as it is not transitive");
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
int display()
{
    printf("\nThe equivalence class is:\n{");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (mat[i][j] == 1)
                printf("(%c,%c)", set[i], set[j]);
        }
    }
    printf("}\n");
}
```

And the output in vscode terminal just stops after this and does not terminate

```
Enter the no. of elements in the set: 3
Enter the elements of the set: 123

Enter the elements of relation in the manner '(a,b)(b,d)...':
(1,1)(2,2)
^C
D:\c>
```

The cursor is just fixed in a newline after the line (1,1)(2,2) until i press ctrl+c
I used getchar() at last but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you compile with warnings enabled (e.g. `-Wall`), the compiler would flag your issue:

```
orig.c:11:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]
 void main()
      ^~~~
orig.c: In function ‘main’:
orig.c:16:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gets’; did you mean ‘fgets’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  gets(set);
  ^~~~
  fgets
orig.c:27:34: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
   for (i = 0;  i < relln - 5;  i + 5)
                                ~~^~~
orig.c: In function ‘adjacency’:
orig.c:78:43: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
  for (i = 1, j = 3;  i < relln - 3;  i + 5, j + 5)
                                           ^
orig.c:78:43: warning: statement with no effect [-Wunused-value]
orig.c:100:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
orig.c: In function ‘display’:
orig.c:161:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
/tmp/ccIGyhw4.o: In function `main':
orig.c:(.text+0x45): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
```

Note the warnings for lines 27 and 78.

Change:

```
for (i = 0;  i < relln - 5;  i + 5)
```

Into:

```
for (i = 0;  i < relln - 5;  i += 5)
```

And, similarly, change:

```
for (i = 1, j = 3;  i < relln - 3;  i + 5, j + 5)
```

Into:

```
for (i = 1, j = 3;  i < relln - 3;  i += 5, j += 5)
```

In both cases, you have increment clauses that do nothing. So, you have infinite loops.

Fix the other warnings as well. And, *never* use `gets`

Comment: I'm using gets after scanf in the beginning of the code to eliminate the newline problem of scanf, is there any other way to use fgets after scanf without the need of gets like above

Comment: Roll your own. Look for `getstr` in my recent answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64902984/how-to-access-an-element-in-the-structure-which-not-the-first-qsort/64903305#64903305 The man page for `gets` explains why it is so dangerous and cites the Mitre article on it [man pages _never_ do that]. And, the linker warns about _not_ using it. I've been programming in C for 40+ years and have never used `gets` [or `scanf`] once in production code.