# Not being able to prompt the user for an input

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to ask the user for an input and count the number of letters of the text. The file compiles well but does ask the user for the input.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <cs50.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    
    int main (void)
        {
    //Promp user for an input
        string s = get_string("Text:");
    
        float letters = 0;
    
        for (int i= 0, n=strlen(s); i<n; i++ )
        {
    
        if (isalpha (s[i]))
        {
                return letters++;
        }
    
        }
        }
```

Comment: That's strange. If the program compiles and links cleanly, no matter what else, the program _will_ prompt for user input (it's the first executable statement of `main`). What OS/environment are you on? And, are you _sure_ you're linking with the correct library? When you compiled, did you turn on warnings (e.g. the `-Wall` option)?

Comment: If you're [still] having trouble, see my recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64902984/how-to-access-an-element-in-the-structure-which-not-the-first-qsort/64903305#64903305 I did a `getstr` function that is somewhat similar to cs50's `get_string`

Comment: Can you run your program under the debugger (e.g. `gdb`), put a breakpoint on `main`, and then single step it?

Comment: Are you running it in the CS50 IDE, or on your computer?

Comment: Thank you all for the reply, I was running in the SC50 Ide and it seems there was a problem on their side, as now all works fine.